# Getting 'expected ',' or ';' before static' error in moduleparam.h while compiling a kernel module on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

While writing a simple kernel module on Ubuntu, I came across the below error in the file `moduleparam.h`  as below

```
./include/linux/moduleparam.h:409:9: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘static’
```

below is the code I am trying to compile.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h> //This for an ARRAY_SIZE()
#include <linux/moduleparam.h> //Module parameters 
#include <linux/stat.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static short my_short = 1;
static long my_long = 9999;
static int my_int = 5;
static char *my_string = "WH";
static int my_array[2] = {429,429};
static int arr_argc = 0;


module_param(my_short,short,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(my_short,"A short integer.");
module_param(my_long,long,S_IRUSR);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(my_long,"A long Integer.");
module_param(my_int,int,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(my_int,"A Integer.")
module_param (my_string,charp,0000);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(my_string,"A character string");
module_param_array (my_array,int, &arr_argc,0000);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(my_array,"An Array of integer");



static int __init start_module(void)
{   
    int i;
    pr_info("Hello, World 5.\n ======================\n");
    pr_info("My_Short is a short integer %d\n",my_short);
    pr_info("My_long is a long integer %d\n",my_long);
    pr_info("My_int is a  integer %d\n",my_int);
    pr_info("My_string is a character string %s\n",my_string);

    for (i=0;i < ARRAY_SIZE(my_array);i++)
        pr_info ("At index %d, we have %d in my_array\n",i,my_array[i]);
    pr_info("god %d arguments in the my_array\n",arr_argc);
    return 0;

}

static void __exit end_module(void)
{
    pr_info("GoodBye! world 5\n");
}

module_init(start_module);
module_exit(end_module);
```

I tried to locate the file moduleparam.h and fix the issue, but i think i dont hold that much programming knowledge at the moment.

Comment: How exactly do you invoke the compiler?

Comment: Have you tried reordering the includes to ensure dependencies are correct?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot ';' at line `MODULE_PARM_DESC(my_int,"A Integer.")`